# How do I display image on server in https client?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, server, next.js

- Server (Express) Working on port 4000, and it has an image at /public/image.png
- Done Setting Express Static File Serving
- Client (Next.js) Working on port 3000

When I test in local,

`<image src="http://localhost:4000/image.png" />` I can see it perfectly.
Directly Access to `http://localhost:4000/image.png` address will show image download popup.

But In Production Server,

`<image src="https://example.com/image.png" />` I cannot see the image.
Directly Access to `https://example.com/image.png` show **Not Found** message on client.

- Production Server Using Proxy with `nginx` + `letsencrypt` enviroment.

Any Help?

Comment: You can serve all the static content with nginx itself, it would be much more performant that using Express for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use an nginx reverse proxy that redirect your requests to your application with port 3000.

But the images are on an different application that runs on 4000

Your nginx configuration might look something like:

```
server {
    server_name example.com
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

What you can do is to add a new location like `images` that redirects to your port 4000 application

```
server {
    server_name example.com
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /images {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Every `http://example.com/images` requests will be direclty redirected to your 4000 port app
Now your images will be available under `http://example.com/images/image.png`

Comment: @Juntae wuhuu :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the image files inside the resource folder if you really want them to display as public.

Comment: I have to save images on server... That images will be displayed several sites.

Comment: Put that image in resource/images folder and try to access it using that link. Or you can also try to access it like the way you follow to access your js/css files. It should work